# Как объяснить правилом ненужность запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

Под кормовой решёткой хранится небольшой запас хлеба, десяток копчёных рыб и бочонок с водой, а на самом борту сидит молодой рыбак и с хвастливой небрежностью (здесь поставила запятую по ошибке) раскуривает верченую папиросу.

Comment: Просто для сведения: Ваше предложение "слеплено" из двух. Вот как правильно у Куприна: _Вода шипит и пенится за бортом и брызжет внутрь, а на самом борту, временами моча нижний край своей куртки в воде, сидит небрежно какой-нибудь молодой рыбак и с хвастливой небрежностью раскуривает верченую папиросу. Под кормовой решеткой хранится небольшой запас крепкой водки, немного хлеба, десяток копченых рыб и бочонок с водой._ http://rulibrary.ru/kuprin/tom_9__ocherki,_vospominaniya,_stati/54

Answer (score 1):

Для постановки запятой нужно **грамматическое обоснование**.

Чтобы доказать ненужность запятой, нужно сделать разбор предложения.

..*.а на самом борту сидит молодой рыбак //и с хвастливой небрежностью  //раскуривает верченую папиросу.*

Грамматическая основа: *сидит рыбак и раскуривает.* ***С хвастливой небрежностью*** — обстоятельство, отнесенное ко второму сказуемому, **нет причин** для его выделения и обособления.

**Лишние запятые** обычно ставятся на месте произносительных пауз, с помощью которых распространенное предложение делится на смысловые части, удобные для произношения.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая в данном случае совсем не необходима, т.к. "с хвастливой небрежностью" в данном случае **относится к сказуемому "раскручивает папиросу" и является обстоятельством образа действия**.  Её постановка возможна **только в том случае**, если мы, скажем, удалим из предложения лишние слова, например союз "и", либо, добавив запятую, сделаем данный оборот обособленным. Также возможны другие вариации предложения, но на них я останавливаться не буду.

Comment: Артём, да у нас с Вами принципиально разные взгляды на выражение своих мыслей

Comment: Тут действительно нарушается порядок. Не может быть такого, что сначала обособляешь, а потом добавляешь запятую (а так у Вас и получалось), только наоборот. Помню, об этом пишет Нора Галь в начале знаменитой своей книжки (о том, что часто встречаются такие ошибки с деепричастными оборотами). ;)

Comment: Неа. Я использовал "получим обособленный оборот" в качестве следствия добавления запятой. Это уже авторский смысл.

Comment: "Получим обособленный оборот, добавив запятую" — тоже верно. А вот "получив ОО, добавим запятую" нельзя сказать, потому что первично действие д. о., и невозможно сначала уже получить ОО, т. е. оборот с запятой, а потом только эту запятую добавить.

Comment: Кто сказал, что я не использую инверсию?

Comment: Хмм, ну какая бы ни была инверсия, всё равно деепричастие и глагол в своих частях относятся к тем же словам, и смысл не меняется, разве нет?